# What is the proper way to use polysorbate to create an emulsion?

Tags: emulsion

I am looking for an emulsifier that will bind my flavouring oil and syrup, but will not destroy the taste. I was told to try  polysorbate 20 and 80. I have mixed the oil and water, and added some polysorbate 80. There is a layer still on top of the syrup that u can't see through, and the bottom 2/3 is cloudy. I can only feel that this hasn't worked. I also thought that polysorbate is supposed to be tasteless, but the stuff in front of me taste disgusting, even a pea sized drop. Am I using polysorbate correctly?

Comment: What is the syrup/oil/polysorbate ratio you're using?

Comment: Maybe polysorbate 20 or polysorbate 80 does not work well with a pure water and oil mixture?

Answer (score 2):

From what I have read, the process is to mix polysorbate with the essential oil, in a 1:1 ratio, until a clear solution is achieved.  Then, add that mixture to your water or flavor syrup. As I understand it, there are several variables, such at pH, temperature, and the other ingredients that might be part of your final product, which could impact the effectiveness of polysorbate.

You could also look into [soy lecithin](http://www.ingredientstodiefor.com/item/Lecithin_Liquid/1352/) as a potential emulsifier for your situation.